# Laravel: How to insert multiple records

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to insert multiple records in my database using Laravel, however when i insert it, it only gives me one record in the database

**Here's my Controller**

```
    public function postCreateAttendance()
{
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'status' => 'required'
    ));


    if ($validate->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::route('viewStudent')->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
    }
    else
    {





        foreach(User::all() as $user):
        foreach(User::whereRaw('isTeacher = "0" and isAdmin = "0"')->get() as $student)
        foreach(User::whereRaw('isTeacher = "1" and isAdmin = "0"')->get() as $teacher)
        //$users[$user->id]=$user->firstname;




        $attendance = new Attendance();
        $attendance->status = Input::get('status');
        $attendance->comment = Input::get('comment');
        $attendance->student_id = $student->id=$student->id;
        $attendance->student_firstname = $student->id=$student->firstname;
        $attendance->student_lastname = $student->id=$student->lastname;
        $attendance->teacher_id = $teacher->id=$teacher->id;
        $attendance->teacher_firstname = $teacher->id=$teacher->firstname;
        $attendance->teacher_lastname = $teacher->id=$teacher->lastname;






        if($attendance->save())
        {
            return Redirect::route('viewStudent')->with('success', 'ATTENDANCE HAS BEEN RECORDED!');
        }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('viewStudent')->with('fail', 'An error occured while creating the attendance.');
    }


        endforeach;


    }
}
```

How can i save multiple records?  Please help Thank You ^_^

Comment: your foreach loop breaks after the first item has been processed due to `if($attendance->save()) { return Redirect ...} else {return Redirect ...}`. Refactor that and you should be done (Redirects should only happen on Exceptions or after the loop has been processed comploeteley). But genarally, your code is not very clear, so you might want to refactor it as a whole (adding some curly braces, correct intendation etc..)

Comment: also consider Bulk inserts via `Attendance::insert()` as this might speed things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are `return`ing during the foreach loop - so only one record is processed. You need to process all the records, then return the route.

Here is some refactoring of your code

```
public function postCreateAttendance()
{
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'status' => 'required'
    ));


    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('viewStudent')->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
    }

        foreach(User::where('isTeacher', '0')->where('isAdmin', '0')->get() as $student) {
              foreach(User::where('isTeacher', '1')->where('isAdmin', '0')->get() as $teacher) {

                    $attendance = new Attendance();
                    $attendance->status = Input::get('status');
                    $attendance->comment = Input::get('comment');
                    $attendance->student_id = $student->id;
                    $attendance->student_firstname = $student->firstname;
                    $attendance->student_lastname = $student->lastname;
                    $attendance->teacher_id = $teacher->id;
                    $attendance->teacher_firstname = $teacher->firstname;
                    $attendance->teacher_lastname = $teacher->lastname;
                    $attendance->save();
               }
          }

      return Redirect::route('viewStudent')->with('success', 'ATTENDANCE HAS BEEN RECORDED!');
}
```

Edit: I've removed the first `foreach(User::all() as $user):` - because at the moment, in your code, it does nothing...?

Comment: That did the trick!!! :D  Thank you!! and yeah the foreach(User::all() as $user): is just a reference hehe sorry about that ^^;;